# How To lookup tuples in Serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**I have models.py like This**

```
GENDER =(
    ('MALE',1),
    ('FEMALE',2),
    ('OTHERS',3)
    )

class User(BaseModel, AbstractUser):
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE,null=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=GENDER,null=True)
```

And Views.py to list student is like this

```
def list(self,request):

    for adm in StudentAdmission.objects.all():
        user = adm.student.user

        tmp['user']  = UserGetSerializer(user).data

        ud = UserDetail.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
        if ud:
            tmp['user_detail'] = UserDetailSerializer(ud.first()).data
```

And serializer.py like This...

```
class UserBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=120,required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=120,required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)


class UserSerializer(UserBaseSerializer):
    gender = serializers.IntegerField()
    type = serializers.IntegerField(default=3)


class UserGetSerializer(UserBaseSerializer):
    gender = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    type = serializers.IntegerField(default=3)

    def get_gender(self, obj):

        #Here Confusion

        return {'id':obj.gender, 'value':value}
```

It returns the output 1 in gender instead of returning male. I want to return male instead of 1 . For that i made a get_gender() function to lookup from the tuple and return the value for that object Id ..
So My Question Is how can i write get_gender() function To lookup the Gender tuple.

Sorry For The English I hope U will Understant My Question

Answer (score 3):

Use model's [`get_FOO_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method:

```
def get_gender(self, obj):
    return obj.get_gender_display()
```

Or just specify is as source of the field:

```
class UserGetSerializer(UserBaseSerializer):
    gender = serializers.CharField(source='get_gender_display')
```

Note your `GENDER` tuple has wrong value. It should be `(actual_value, human_readable)` like this:

```
GENDER =(
    (1, 'MALE'),
    (2, 'FEMALE'),
    (3, 'OTHERS')
)
```

Comment: this is the correct approach to get the display value. however, in his case, the choices are not correct . should be the other way around ( 1, "MALE"). otherwise, he will get 1 even if it uses the display method. So you can mention this in your answer too.